# Bugzilla extension. How to check if custom field empty?

Tags: perl, bugzilla

How to check condition if some custom field empty?

For example, it's possible to check that qa_contact is not set.

```
sub object_end_of_set_all {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    my $object = $args->{'object'};
    if ($object->{'bug_status'} eq 'RESOLVED') {        
        if ($object->{'qa_contact'} eq "") {             
            ThrowUserError("empty_qa_contact");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there is same way for custom field e.g. cf_test ?

I know that to save custom field in variable, need to:

```
my $test = new Bugzilla::Field({ name => 'cf_test' });
```

Which method can be used to get its value or check if it's not empty ?

Comment: I found in DB mysql that table 'bugs' contains a text that I've written in custom field.  This table contains qa_contact and bug_status. Cannot understand why it's not return value through $args->{'object'} for custom field ?

Comment: what class is `$object`?  what version of Bugzilla?

Comment: If I'm not wrong the 'object is taking from Hook:  Bugzilla::Hook::process('object_end_of_set_all',  
                            { object => $self, params => \%field_values });
This Hook is placed within set_all subroutine of package Bugzilla::Object.
The class is Object, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out two problems:
1. After executing ThrowUserError("...") any object (cf_test or even bugzilla fields) is always NULL.
2. If to use Hook "object_end_of_set_all" for custom field then only a cached values are showed for a custom field.

The answer is to use different Hook:

```
sub bug_end_of_update {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    my ($bug, $old_bug, $timestamp, $changes) = @$args{qw(bug old_bug timestamp changes)};
    if ($bug->bug_status eq 'RESOLVED') {
        if ($bug->cf_test eq "") {
            ThrowUserError("test_is_empty");
        }
    }
}
```